# Syntax error highlight for valid syntax - Python 3.6

Tags: python, emacs, elpy

Below is the `elpy-config`,

```
Elpy Configuration

Virtualenv........: None
RPC Python........: 3.6.1 (/usr/bin/python3.6)
Interactive Python: python3.6 (/usr/bin/python3.6)
Emacs.............: 25.2.1
Elpy..............: 1.15.1
Jedi..............: 0.10.2
Rope..............: 0.9.4-1
Importmagic.......: 0.1.7
Autopep8..........: 1.3.1
Yapf..............: 0.16.2
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/usr/local/bin/flake8)
```

but syntax checker do not accept f-string syntax of python 3.6,

[image]

---

`C-u C-c C-c` gives correct output in emacs, but syntax checker does recognise this syntax

```
> Hello, MICHAEL. Welcome!
```

**Question:**

Do I need to upgrade syntax checker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you have Flake8 installed for Python 3.6?

According to the [docs](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/#installation):

> It is **very** important to install **Flake8** on the correct version of Python for your needs. If you want **Flake8** to properly parse new language features in Python 3.5 (for example), you need it to be installed on 3.5 for **Flake8** to understand those features. In many ways, Flake8 is tied to the version of Python on which it runs.

It seems like the version of Flake8 you have at `/usr/local/bin/flake8` doesn't handle Python 3.6.

Comment: There are detailed instructions in link to the docs. It's not that it's a Flake8 version you need to upgrade to, it's that Flake8 needs to be installed on Python3.6.